# Issue with animating geom_bar using gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, gganimate

I am having an issue with gganimate and I would like some help, please.

I am trying to display a bar plot and then animate it over some years but I have no output and no error displayed. Is there a bug or am I missing something?

I am using data about accidents at work in the EU.
My R version is: 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)

Hopefully, the following code demonstrates the problem

```
library(eurostat)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(gganimate)

# get Eurostat data: accidents at work
d_list <- get_eurostat('hsw_ph3_02')

## cast the list into an R data frame
df <- as.data.frame(d_list)

# get data 
data_UE27_time <- subset(df, df$wrkenv == "TOTAL" & df$geo =="EU27" & 
                             df$severity =="FAT" & df$sex == "M" & df$age == "TOTAL" &
                             df$unit == "NR" & df$nace_r2 != "TOTAL" & df$nace_r2 != "A_C-N", 
                         select=c(nace_r2,values,time))

#animated bar plot
gp <- ggplot(data = data_UE27_time, aes(x = nace_r2, y = values))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
   transition_time(time) +
  labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}")
```

Comment: Just do this `animate(gp)`.

Comment: ggplot plot objects are not supported using animate

Comment: They are, look at my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(magick)
library(png)
library(gganimate)

gp <- data_UE27_time %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = nace_r2, y = values, group = time)) +
          geom_bar(stat="identity") +
          transition_time(time) +
          labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}")

animate(gp, nframes = 10)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: **To downvoter**, If you can remotely explain your reason, I will pick one of your top answers and will award 500 reps bounty to it.

Comment: Thank you very much @M--   :-)

Comment: @B.Sarah You're welcome. I have to confess that I couldn't get plotly to animate barplot though. It could be a follow up question. Cheers.